# Where I use @ExtendsWith(MockitoExtension.class) and @SpringBootTest anyone clarify me with example

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito

I'm beginner in Spring boot till now I have complete the REST Operations(GET,POST,PUT,DELETE) with MYSQL as a database and I want to write the unit test cases for Controller class and Service class I use Mockito framework for writing test cases and I don't know when I use.

I'm stuck with

1. where I use `@SpringBootTest` and `@ExtendsWith(MockitoExtension.class)` ?
2. `@SpringBootTest` itself enough?

Comment: Use SpringBootTest if you want to bring up your entire application. WebMvcTest if you want to test the web layer. InjectMocks for single class tests. You could write an entire book which approach is the best - and it depends on your app as well.

Comment: Depends on what you want to test: do you want to mock your dependencies and set up everything manually, or do you want Spring to bootstrap your application context, start your real application and then test its integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SpringBootTest used to integrate test environment, enables you to test controllers, services, other repositories.

if you're writing unit tests for your controller and service classes using Mockito, you'll typically use @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) to enable Mockito and then mock any dependencies of the class you're testing.

Comment: For controllers you ideally should be using `@WebMvcTest` combined with `@MockBean`.